# AlarmManager does not call service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have set an AlarmManager to repeatedly calling my service to update my database. But it seems my service never get called by this AlarmManager.
I put a system.out in service, but it never printed in output.

I have this piece of code in my MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceAreaAlarmReceiver.class);

final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ServiceAreaAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstMillis + 60000, 60000, pIntent);
```

and this is my manifest :

```
<receiver
    android:name=".service.ServiceAreaAlarmReceiver" />

<service
    android:name=".service.UpdateDatabaseService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

and this is my service :

```
public class ServiceAreaAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("got here");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateDatabaseService.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to change change your receiver in manifest to `<receiver
            android:name=".service.ServiceAreaAlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" />` ?

Comment: yes, i tried that too ...

Comment: okay here is what i used to set alarm but it's exact so use exact to confirm it entering into the broadcastreceiver  it's just a second after you set the alarm to confirm it's working 
`AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ServiceAreaAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 , pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute`

Comment: That's exactly what i do, except RTC_WAKEUP that i am using ELAPSED TIME

Comment: It worked by using RTC_WAKEUP :|, but I want to call it every minute, how can i use this for that purpose ?

Comment: Have you tried it? https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#examples-of-elapsed-real-time-alarms

Comment: yes, but it not worked, like the code i attached to my question

Comment: you can setexact inside the receiver itself everytime and adding 60000 instead of 1000 for 1 minute, that's a way to do it. or
you can setinexact for the RTC_WAKEUP like this
`am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 ,60000, pi);` but take into consideration that setInexactRepeating differs starting Marshmellow API versions same goes and for all devices you will need to use setRepeating as well